# Multidimensional array with foreach loop

Tags: php

**Code**

```
print_r($_SESSION['itmCheck']);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [Pid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 9
        )

    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

Want to save all the data in database and show this format in

```
INSERT INTO `cart`( `p_id`, `quantity`) VALUES (pid[0],quantity[0],pid[1],quantity[1])
```

Comment: `I want to` is not a __question__.

Comment: Where is the `foreach` attempt? Also your query is invalid. It'd be `(pid[0],quantity[0]),(pid[1],quantity[1])`

Comment: Research the correct MySQL [INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) syntax

Comment: for($i=0; $i<count($Pid); $i++){$query = "INSERT INTO `cart`( `p_id`, `quantity`) VALUES ('".pid[$i]."',.'"quantity[$i]."')";}

Comment: @vSugumar That isn't a good approach, and will make only the last value inserted.

Comment: @user3783243 he needs insert it in each iteration

Answer (score 0):

I can come up with two simple ways of looping through your data.

```
$insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO `cart`( `p_id`, `quantity`) VALUES ';

$dataRaw = [
    'Pid' => [
        0 => 8,
        1 => 10,
        2 => 9,
    ],
    'quantity' => [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 2,
        2 => 3,
    ],
];

// Foreach with combined array 
$dataCombined = array_combine($dataRaw['Pid'], $dataRaw['quantity']);

$valuesCombined = array();

foreach ($dataCombined as $key => $value) {
    $valuesCombined[] = '(' . $key . ', ' . $value . ')';
}

echo $insertQuery . implode(',', $valuesCombined) . ';';
// //

echo '<br><br>';

// For loop with array index
$valuesRaw = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataRaw['Pid']); $i ++) {
    $valuesRaw[] = '(' . $dataRaw['Pid'][$i] . ', ' . $dataRaw['quantity'][$i] . ')';
}

echo $insertQuery . implode(',', $valuesRaw) . ';' ;
// //
```

The above code outputs:

```
INSERT INTO `cart`( `p_id`, `quantity`) VALUES (8, 1),(10, 2),(9, 3);

INSERT INTO `cart`( `p_id`, `quantity`) VALUES (8, 1),(10, 2),(9, 3);
```